# Adding new custom field in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

Is there a way to add a new field to all the documents in a index in kibana ? For example , lets assume, i have the age of all the users in my elastic kibana. And i want to separate them into two categories as **Below 50 and Above 50** . So if there is a user who is **23 years** of age , he should have a category value as **Below 50**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to add another option to the one offered by @dravit. If you don't want to modify your documents, and you only need that extra field to run analysis in Kibana, you can add a scripted field to your index pattern, so that the `category` value is calculated at query time.

Ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html

The script for your scripted field would be something as easy as

```
doc['age'].value > 50 ? "Above 50" : "Below 50"
```

Comment: @dravit & glenacota .  I have data of 10000 users and a dashboard to view the health details. Now the requirement was to have dashboards based on category.Instead of creating 3 different dashboards for 3 different categories , i am planning to add a new field to all users called category and mark them as below 50, 50-75 and above 75. and using the category field , i am planning to use the Controls visual in kibana. As I select the category in drop-down , the visuals in the dashboard will change accordingly.

Comment: You can create filters out of scripted fields in Kibana. I'd argue that if your requirements will change again, scripted fields are the most flexible solution for you, because they won't change the documents. `BUT` be aware that they come with a computational cost, because they have to be computed at query time. If the loading time of your dashboards with scripted fields is satisfactory for you, then I'd go for it.

Comment: was your question answered, @UMAMAHESWAR?

Comment: I added a scripted field and it is working good now . Danke :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. What you want is **update-by-query** and **painless-scripts**.

They will give you flexibility to do something of this sort

```
POST /users/string/_update_by_query
{
"script": "ctx._source.category = ctx._source.age > 50 ? "Above 50" : "Below 50"
}
```

Comment: how does this work? if(category >50) , then above else below 50 ) . Right ? What if I need to have 3 values - below 50, from 50-75, above 75.

Comment: yup, that's about right. as the name goes, "painless-scripts" (pun intended), you can also use if-else statements in the scripts.